# how to remove jQuery mobile effect with jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using submenu / menu option of jQuery UI. But I also include jQuery mobile in my project.

Actually when I only include jQuery UI it looks good as I want. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P962c/))

But when I include jQuery mobile it removes the effect, looking awkward. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P962c/1/))

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Addyston</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Delphi</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Delphi</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can we remove the CSS effect in menu option of jQuery mobile?

Comment: What css effect, specifically?

Comment: All of the JQM style applied to the menu I'd guess.

Comment: yes ..I need to remove all style of jqm in menu

Comment: Please check my fiddle u can analyse what happen when both are added

Comment: If it's really important for you include JQM, you can download the JMQ CSS and edit how ever you want, or you can download the [JQM CSS Structure](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)  and include this file. Maybe this can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have gone through the fiddles you have created
if possible you can use jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 instead of jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1 that is conflicting